# Equivalent to DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs.Cancel for WPF DataGrid in an async context

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid

I have a **DataGrid** for which I set an event handler on **RowEditEnding** to perform a data update and use **DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs.Cancel** to keep the user on the same row if the update fails for any reason. In a synchronous context, this works fine. However, I am refactoring the data updates to an async/await pattern and want to preserve the same user interaction - that is, the user cannot leave unsaved changes on a row - changes must either update successfully or the user must explicitly cancel the edits. I also want to minimize round trips to the data store - only do an update on a **RowEditEnding** or equivalent event.

The problem is that with the async/await pattern, the outcome of an attempted update is only determined after the **RowEditEnding** method has returned, so I can't use **DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs.Cancel** any more. It would seem that I would need to ensure the edited row is selected and in edit mode, but calling **BeginEdit()** i.e. the parameterless overload doesn't reactivate edit mode (**RowEditEnding** isn't fired if I tab out of the row).

What could I do to force the data grid back into an editing state outside the scope of a **RowEditEnding** event?

The synchronous way (worked fine):

```
public class MyData
{
    // Properties, etc...


    public void Save()
    {
        // Synchronously saves to database, throws exception on error
    }
}


void MyGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var item = (MyData)e.Row.Item;
        try
        {
            item.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The async/await way... doesn't work as needed:

```
public class MyData
{
    // Properties, etc...


    public Task Save()
    {
        // Asynchronously saves to database, throws exception on error
    }
}


async void MyGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var item = (MyData)e.Row.Item;
        try
        {
            await item.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // We get here on an exception thrown from Save
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            e.Cancel = true; // <== pointless, we're not in the execution scope of the event handler any more

            MyGrid.SelectedItem = item; // We reselect the offending item
            MyGrid.BeginEdit(); // Has no apparent effect
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around, not sure if it qualifies as "best" practice:

```
public class MyData
{
    // Properties, etc...


    public Task Save()
    {
        // Asynchronously saves to database, throws exception on error
    }
}


void MyGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var item = (MyData)e.Row.Item;
        try
        {
            // Force the awaitable task to complete synchronously
            // Have to use Task.Run to keep the awaited task from deadlocking
            var task = Task.Run(async () => { await item.Save(); });
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // We get here on an exception thrown from Save
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            e.Cancel = true; // <== Can do this just as before
        }
    }
}
```